send notifications for multiple device token above (2000) with Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) using Laravel 10
I was using the Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) to send my notification that I could send the message to all 1000 devices in each CURL. Now when they update and use Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) I can't send token to device by device, if I put them in a foreach loop it will take much longer time and also more performance if I increase the extra time for my application server (php 8.1 .0). It made me worry about the security aspects.
Also: I delete my server key in firebase console (legacy).
Services:
`
namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class FcmService
{
    protected $client;
    protected $url;
    protected $credentialsFilePath;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->credentialsFilePath = public_path('xxxxxx.json');
        $this->url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx/messages:send';
    }

 public function sendMultiNotification(array $tokens, string $title, string $body)
{
    $responses = [];
    $batchSize = 500; // Maximum allowed tokens per request

    // Split tokens into batches
    foreach (array_chunk($tokens, $batchSize) as $tokenBatch) {
        $message = [
            'message' => [
                'tokens' => $tokenBatch, // Use 'tokens' for multiple device tokens
                'notification' => [
                    'title' => $title,
                    'body' => $body,
                ],
            ],
        ];

        try {
            $response = $this->client->post($this->url, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->generateAccessToken(),
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'json' => $message,
            ]);

            // Log the response status and body
            \Log::info('FCM Response Status: ' . $response->getStatusCode());
            \Log::info('FCM Response Body: ' . $response->getBody());

            $responses[] = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            \Log::error('FCM Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            $responses[] = ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
        }
    }

    return $responses; // Return all responses for each batch
}

    protected function generateAccessToken()
    {
        $credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->credentialsFilePath), true);
        $now = time();
        $payload = [
            'iss' => $credentials['client_email'],
            'sub' => $credentials['client_email'],
            'iat' => $now,
            'exp' => $now + 3600,
            'aud' => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/',
        ];

        return JWT::encode($payload, $credentials['private_key'], 'RS256');
    }
}

----------::------------
Controller:

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\FcmService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FcmController1 extends Controller
{
    protected $fcmService;

    public function __construct(FcmService $fcmService)
    {
        $this->fcmService = $fcmService; // Assign the injected service to the class property
    }


    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        $tokens =['xxxxx',xxx2'];
$title = 'Your Notification Title';
$body = 'Your Notification Body';

$responses = $this->fcmService->sendMultiNotification($tokens, $title, $body);

        return response()->json($response);
    }
}

Error:

"error": "Client error: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/newbonuscard/messages:send resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:\n{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"tokens\" at 'message': Prot (truncated...)\n"


As the error says, you're passing a tokens property to the API, which is doesn't expect. The API is pretty well documented, so I recommend following that here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest From there, it seems you need to pass a single token in the token (singular) property.

what I do if I need to send an array of token?

You'll need to start by migrating to the cloud messaging package and using the sendMulticast method, which allows you to send up to 500 tokens in a single request. This will improve performance by reducing server saturation.
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/7.15.0/cloud-messaging.html

You loop over the array in your code, and call the API for each individual token. Since your code already handles the batch sizes, you can just change the foreach to handle one token at a time (instead of 500 at a time).

@Lhony: check this note in the Firebase PHP docs: "The sendMulticast method stems from a time where Firebase had a (now shutdown) dedicated API endpoint for multicast messages. It is now a wrapper for the sendAll() method. “Legacy” is also the reason why the returned report is named MulticastSendReport." --- So it's better to call sendAll() directly when you use this package/SDK.

$credentialsPath = public_path('pppppp-firebase-adminsdk.json');
$firebase = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($credentialsPath);
$messaging = $firebase->createMessaging();
$notification = [
'title' => $title,
'body' => $body,
];
$deviceTokens = [
'1xxxx',  '2xxxxx',  '1500 XXXX'
];
$message1 = CloudMessage::new()
->withNotification($notification);
$report = $messaging->sendMulticast($message1, $deviceTokens );
echo 'Successful sends: '.$report->successes()->count().PHP_EOL;
echo 'Failed sends: '.$report->failures()->count().PHP_EOL;
